# Angular frequency - Cannot explain solution

Tags: physics

Hello I'm learning some electrical engineering today but cannot come to the solution.
$w = 2π*f$
How is:
$2π*295.4 kHz = 1.86 * 106 s^{-1}$

cannot figure out what $1.86 * 106 s^{-1}$ should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

1. $$\text{f}_{\left[\text{Hz}\right]}=\frac{1}{\text{t}_{\left[\text{s}\right]}}$$
2. $$\omega_{\left[\text{rad/s}\right]}=2\pi\cdot\text{f}_{\left[\text{Hz}\right]}=2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{\text{t}_{\left[\text{s}\right]}}=\frac{2\pi}{\text{t}_{\left[\text{s}\right]}}$$

So, when $\text{f}_{\left[\text{Hz}\right]}=295.4\cdot1000=295400\space\text{Hz}$, we get:

- $$\omega_{\left[\text{rad/s}\right]}=2\pi\cdot295400=590800\pi\approx1856052.94\space\text{rad/s}$$

Comment: Thank you i know its a poor question! Thank you that helped me.

Comment: @raviolican You're welcome, I'm glad that I could help. I'm very interested in electronics so, nice question :)